# The argument docData must implement the interface IVsTextStream ERROR after importing image as resource

Tags: c#, image, resources, picturebox

I am coding a UserInterface for our ETO Autodesk CAD Software. This is done as a simple add on in C#. Effectively its a class Library DLL placed under a certain path.

Now at the point I need to show images in the user Interface I get this message:  The argument docData must implement the interface IVsTextStream. 
The code is not saving anymore and eventually the complete windows form is suddenly empty.

I try to use pictureBox or add the image directly on the tab of a tabcontrol. I used different file formats like png or bmp. Always the same Error.

[image]

Hope someone can help. Internet does not show anything.

Comment: In general, you'll get better results here if you show your code.

Comment: I do not change any code here. I simply import a picture as resource and get this Error . Thank you anyway :)

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Same Problem occurs to me for a windows application. I have searched for the same issue and find somewhere that "deleting resx file from the form may help you." Well, my issue was resolve after doing so.

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: This does not help me. :(

Answer (score 1):

VS2019 (16.9.2) Got the `The argument docData must implement the interface IVsTextStream`

My case happens when importing new thing to resx. (Inserting an image to the form or control also counted as importing thing to resx) I compared my project the working one and  noticed wrong file dependency, I made the following fixes:

Note that this is WinForm for .NET framework, not .NET core. When creating new project in VS there are 2 separated project templates:

- **"Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)"** <- I'm using this one
- **"Windows Forms App"** <- This one will be using newer gen of cross platform .NET family

#### My fix

1. I found that my resx was parented in wrong fashion. `MainForm.resx` should be parented (dependent upon) `MainForm.cs` [image]
2. I found that my resx was associated with wrong tool. Correct one for my form's resx is 'blank'. Note that Custom Tool for application global `Resources.resx` should be `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`
   [image]

#### For OP's case of blank form after error dialog

I also suffered from this, and I has confirmed that the designer somehow confused and actually REMOVED all of your form contents. This cannot be undone, unless you have version control, sadly.