# I get this error when I put an image in a button or picturebox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

When I add a standard button, click on "image" in the property, a dialog box opens asking me if I want to save the changes to FMain.res. I click on save, another dialog box opens and I choose "Project resource file" and import my PNG image then I click on Ok and my image is displayed on the button.

I test by running the debugger and get the famous error message above.

I tried the same steps in a new project but it works fine, I don't get any error message for displaying an image in a button or a pictureBox.

I get for this error The argument docData must implement the interface IVsTextStream

The problem comes from my project

I have a simple button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         ......
        }
```

I also noticed that some .resx files have been added to the project (circled in red).

[image]

I tried that but no change [The argument docData must implement the interface IVsTextStream ERROR after importing image as resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811682/the-argument-docdata-must-implement-the-interface-ivstextstream-error-after-impo)

Thanks

Comment: The dependency structure of this Project is disrupted. A `.Designer.cs ` file should not be a dependency of a `.resx` file. Must be a dependency of the main Form class -- You can fix these dependencies by manually editing the Project's file

Comment: Thanks, I understand better the source of the problem.
Which file are you talking about to modify manually?

Do you have a clue as to what to modify?

Comment: Hi, as Jimi said, the dependency structure of this project is broken. Usually the way we use is to clean and rebuild the solution

Comment: Thanks, I had already cleaned it and when I rebuild the solution I always get the same error message

Comment: Those are  hard-coded dependencies, there's nothing to clean. Create a new Project, add a second Form, build the Project. After that, inspect its `.csproj` file and compare the dependencies you find there with your own. You'll figure it out -- It would be interesting to understand how you got this weird result, though. I hope you didn't add Resource files manually. Or you picked *Ignore and continue* when a VS prompt  reported a build issue

Comment: @Jimi So thank you very much because I did what you said and opened and compared the 2 .csproj files with notepad. I noticed that there were a few extra lines (see screenshot) and after deleting these lines I no longer have any problems or error messages to put images... I hope this will help others... Thanks a million again!
https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=23/22/3dfb.png